# Is it a common thing in American English to refer to Great Britain as "England"?

Tags: word-usage

Is it a common thing in American English to refer to Great Britain as "England"?

EDIT:
By "common" I mean "happening  to more than 85% of USA population".

Comment: By your use of the definite article, are you distinguishing between 'the great' (intensified by capitalisation to 'the Great') Britain and 'Great Britain'? I'm not sure that Americans as a whole think of Britain with such deference.

Comment: @Lawrence - Not really. As a non-native English speaker I often make mistakes in using the definite article. What's the difference between 'the Great Britain' and 'Great Britain'?

Comment: It used to be far more common to refer to the UK as England. Now that the Scots are anxious to abandon the Brexit south, Americans may be forced to call it England again.

Comment: @brilliant The version with "the" refers to Britain and uses "the Great" purposely as an adjective - as with "the great surgeon" or more expressively, "the Great surgeon". The version without "the" simply references the name "Great Britain" with no more thought about 'great' there than the novelty / 'new'ness of "New Zealand".

Comment: @Lawrence - I see. Thanks for sharing that. These nuisances are quite important, but often slip non-native speakers' minds.

Comment: _England_ is shorter, and England is in the same place as Great Britain, not to mention Scotland, Wales, Northern Ireland, or the Channel Islands. They talk English of one sort or another, and that's close enough for Americans, who don't see why there's so much fuss about the terminology.

Comment: "U K" is even shorter than England. This American prefers U K.

Comment: Define *common*, please. No, educated Americans don't say *England* when they mean the *United Kingdom* or *Great Britain* or the other constituents thereof. But I might write something like *if he is a tenured professor, then I'm the queen of England*, despite the fact that I'm well aware the crowns have been united since 1707. It's also common to say things like *London, England* and *London is the capital of England*, because, well, both are true, even though London is more accurately and importantly the capital of the whole enterprise as well and not just the English bit.

Comment: I will say that many residents of the USA **do** in fact use "England" when referring to the United Kingdom, in particular when they wish to refer to the island of Great Britain, excluding the other territories of the UK.  Of course, I have no idea what the Americans in Canada, Mexico, Brazil or other countries of the American continent may use.

Comment: I suggest there are those who are fully aware of the difference and tend to choose 'England' automatically, and those who just don't know about the difference. They may be combined, or treated as different.

Comment: @choster is correct in saying educated Americans. England is not the same place as Great Britain, it is *part* of Great Britain, which comprises England, Wales and Scotland. And Great Britain is part of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland (U.K.). If you were to call someone from Great Britain 'English' and they happened to be Scottish, they would be very insulted indeed. And the Scots have a reputation for head butting, so I wouldn't risk it personally! :) I guess the question is, what percentage of Americans know the difference between England and Great Britain?

Comment: @GGx - " I guess the question is, what percentage of Americans know the difference between England and Great Britain?" - No, the question is exactly about what it asks about.

Comment: @brilliant you mistake my meaning, I didn't say, 'I guess *your* question is'.

Comment: @GGx - Oops! I see now. Sorry!

Comment: @brilliant NP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Americans almost never have occasion to talk about Great Britain, the largest island in the Northwest European archipelago. Since they don't mention it, they have little opportunity to get the terminology wrong.

But it does seem to be the case that Americans often refer to the United Kingdom as "England".